# How to make data queries, limited by a child key in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

it is my first application with firebase and I found a problem that I find it difficult to solve.

The following happens:

- I have a series of users in my application and they can have access, or not, to videos.
- The videos accept certain users according to a process that runs in the backend, and add it into video path.

My structure is something like that:

[image]

I want to be able to consult all the videos to which the user has access, that is that they are in the users key of any video.

Is there any way to do it?

From already thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have a node of Videos with the IDs of the different videos, that's excellent !

What you should do now is iterate inside your `videos` - `users` and get all those key values, those values are the users that belongs to that video.

Pseudocode

```
for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   //Users that belong to this video
    String userID = snapshot.getKey();

   //For each user you can get their data

   databaseRef.child("users").child(userID).addListenerForSingleValue(...
     //get the data of the users who belong to that video
...}
```